# How to start Excel as a different user?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, microsoft-excel

How can I start Excel as a different user? I'm using Win XP and Excel 2003

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run a program with admin privilege](http://superuser.com/questions/371432/how-to-run-a-program-with-admin-privilege)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on the EXE, then click "Run As..."

Comment: Thanks, it works! I found this excel.exe from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be able to do this by creating a shortcut to Excel and then shift-right-clicking the shortcut. You should see a **Run As** option. But there is a standard Windows service that must be running in the background or else the option is not shown:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294676

Comment: This only works on the actual exe - "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\excel.exe" - not on the **start > program files > microsoft office** menu entry. That doesn't appear to be a normal shortcut.

Comment: That would be why I said *by creating a shortcut to Excel*

Answer (score 0):

Try **[ShellRunas](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc300361.aspx)** which is part of Microsoft's SysInternals suite of utilities.

Comment: I downloaded this but it does not seem to do anything. I tried : C:\>ShellRunas excel. It says it cannot find ShellRunas.

Comment: It is a shell extension so you should see it on the context menu when you right click on an executable or shortcut. It's not a command line utility.